# Changing autocomplete source from jQuery but not working?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, autocomplete

I am trying to implement auto-complete text box using JQuery.  I have a dropdown list and a textbox, Trying to attach auto-complete text feature by dropdown list item selection but it is not working,I am using razor.

Here is my razor code.

```
@Html.DropDownList("SearchBy", new SelectList(ViewBag.SearchBy, "Value", "Text"), "--Search By--", new { onchange = "showcontrol(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);" })
 @Html.TextBox("Term")
```

JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    showcontrol = function (id) {
    $("#Term").attr("data-otf-autocomplete", "@Url.Action("AutocompleteState")");                
}
});
</script>
```

Here i am able to change autocomplete soruce path dynamically but it was not working. Please help me some one.

Answer (score 0):

Change your HtmlHelper dropdown to this:

```
@Html.DropDownList("SearchBy", new SelectList(ViewBag.SearchBy, "Value", "Text"), "--Search By--")
```

Removing the obtrusive javascript.

Then bind your change event as follows:

```
$('#SearchBy').change(function () {
    $("select option:selected").each(function () {
        showcontrol($(this).val())
    });
})
```

After your showcontrol function declaration and you will be good to go.